# Список лексем Си

Tags: c

Доброго времени суток!

Кто может написать или скинуть где перечислены все лексемы языка Си (не Си++)

Answer (score 6):

В стандарте языка, конечно.

Вот вам официальный стандарт C11: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf. Вам будет интересен, скорее всего, раздел 6.4.

---

Список *всех* лексем, конечно, привести невозможно, т. к. любой идентификатор является лексемой. Но в стандарте есть по крайней мере полная и окончательная *классификация* лексем.